# HTML form - javascript - automate query - button with validation form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, automation

I need to use a public site to get a registration number. This registration number can be chosen but only if it is not yet in use.

Unfortunately, the site does not provide the availability: I need to make a suggestion in a form and I get the return from the site (ok or in use)

I would like to automate the submission of the form to test for all possibilities (from 10.000 to 99.999).

I use this code

> document.getElementById("fieldN20993").value ='99999' ;
> document.getElementsByName(";check")[0].click();

but the button to submit the form is only visible once the autovalidation has checked the validity of the submission (ie this is a number between 10.000 and 99.999)

what is the best way to automate?

- simulate a tab key to launch the validation and get the submission button
- or force the validation
- or manage to bypass the validation
- or submit without clicking on the button

many thanks in advance
Best,

Comment: `";check"` - there is a stray semi-colon in there which shouldn't be. If you want to test all possibilities from 10,000 to 99,999 you would probably be legitimately flagged as a spammer. Do you have permission to abuse this site as you hope to do? Presumably there is no API so I would guess this is likely against their T&Cs

Comment: I went through their T&C which are very short and there is no provision on the limitation of use (which is very surprising for such a public site). the ; seems to me necessary as it is the name of the field. My main issue is that the button cannot be clicked if it does not appear on the page (which is the case as long as the form validation process has not been done)

Comment: can you submit the data without actually loading the page - ie: would curl work?